# Why java Stream.sorted() gives different result?

Tags: java, java-stream

That's my code:

```
@Test
public void testStream() {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("I", "love", "you", "too");
    Collections.sort(list, (s1, s2) -> {
        if (s1 == null)
            return -1;
        if (s2 == null)
            return 1;
        return s1.length() - s2.length();
    });
    list.stream().sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
    list.forEach(l -> {
        System.out.println(l);
    });
}
```

And the result is:

```
{I,love,too,you}
{I,you,too,love}
```

I learned that `forEach()` is a terminal operation and the right order is last one?

Comment: You could have used a method reference in the last line of code as well - `list.forEach(System.out::println)`. It's doesn't matter for one being a terminal operation and the other being an intermediate operation. The `sort`ing implementation for both your approaches are different and that is why you're looking at a different output for both of them as well (if that's your criteria to judge what is correct.)

Answer (score 2):

`.sorted()` with no parameters gives you natural order. However, you give a length comparator to `Collections.sort`.

Thus, the first line is sorted alphabetically, but the second is sorted lengthwise — exactly as you requested.

If you passed the same comparator to `.sorted(...)`, you would get the same result.

Comment: To add to it the `Comparator` as defined manually is flawed to perform a subtraction of length, it could be better defined as `list.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::length))` where it also reads clearly what it does.

Comment: @Naman lengths are one of the special cases where subtraction works, as there are never negative values in the input. Still, implementing it manually bears unnecessary complexity, so does implementing `null` checks when the list doesn’t contains `null`s. But I’d use `comparingInt` instead of `comparing`…